# Edit custom post type admin menu link

Tags: posts, categories, customization

I'm looking to edit a custom post type's menu link in the WordPress admin - Is this possible?

For example, currently its

`/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=application`

and I want to update this with

`/wp-admin/edit.php?s&post_status=all&post_type=application&cat=36&paged=1`

Thank you for your time

Comment: No clue if possible at all but you can play around with [this](https://generatewp.com/post-status/) online tool. Just curious, WHY? Or look [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-status-menu-items/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `admin_menu` hook. You will be able to loop over all menus.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpse_306432_edit_post_type_admin_menu', 11);
function wpse_306432_edit_post_type_admin_menu()
{
    global $menu;

    foreach($menu as $k => $v){
        if($v[1] == 'edit_applications') // possibly 'edit_application', I'm not sure
        {
            $menu[$k][2] = 'edit.php?post_status=all&post_type=application&cat=36&paged=1'; // I modify your query
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Should work for you :)

Don't hesitate to add a nice :

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($menu);
echo '</pre>';
die();
```

After `global $menu` to understand how it works, and change more !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer :) That looks like a better solution that what i've come up with!

I've added javascript to the admin and updated the link that way

```
function custom_admin_js() {
$url = get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/library/js/wp-admin-XXX.js';
if( current_user_can( 'XX' ) ){ 
    echo '"<script type="text/javascript" src="'. $url . '"></script>'";
}; } add_action('admin_footer', 'custom_admin_js');
```